# How to send openssl s_client -connect stdout and stderr to /dev/null?

Tags: bash, openssl, stdout, stderr

I have following bash script that checks the existence of a given SSL client certificate in Apache.

```
#!/bin/bash
cert=$1
echo | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 | grep -q $cert > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo $cert "client cert already exist"
else
  #Create a new client cert in Apache
fi
```

Even though I am sending stdout and stderr of openssl command to /dev/null, the command is still showing the following error to the console!

depth=3 C = OM, O = ORG, OU = For Staging, CN = ROOT CA - 1 verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain verify return:0 /C=om/O=o/CN=MY_CERT
DONE

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the CA certificate in the appropriate trust store. In OpenSSL's case, load it via `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` or `SSL_load_verify_locations`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my requirement is that how can I send that error  into /dev/null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually sending `openssl`'s stderr to `/dev/null`, but `grep`'s.

To send `openssl`'s stderr to `/dev/null` you need to put the redirection into the same part of the pipe as the `openssl` invocation. And as you're using `grep -q` you don't need any I/O redirection on `grep`.

This shoud do it:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 2>/dev/null | grep -q $cert
```